# I've got a library file (.a). How can I go backwards from this to get some pseudo source code?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

Specifically, I'd just like to check out what API calls are made by the library, and a few of the static strings that are in there too.

Is this doable, and what some basic steps I can take to get started? The library is for a universal iOS app.

Comment: Yes, it is doable.  It's called "decompiling" or "reverse engineering" and depending on what library it is, it may violate the terms of its use and forfeit your privilege to use it should this fact be exposed.  Anyway, just search for decompiling.

Comment: https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/download_demo.shtml Here is demo of probably the best disassembler IDA. Works with obj-C code very well, understands "fat" binaries. And it does it much much better than the Hopper from my experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strings_%28Unix%29) unix command could help you get the static strings.

To get some general info on libraries linked (and a lot more), use `otool`

e.g. `otool -tV <library.a>` could get you started, if you know what you're looking for grepping in there might be helpful.

If you want to get something resembling 'readable' code though, you'll need to decompile/disassemble the library (which might not be permitted). I'm sure tools could be found to help you with that.

Comment: It's working in macOS or not ? If yes how can i do that

Answer (score 1):

[Hopper](http://www.hopperapp.com) is a wonderful tool that does exactly what you are looking for.